# Why won't the result of a function work as a clause in a when statement in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following (edited for length) Kotlin functions:

```
fun getType(obj: Any?): String {
    if (obj != null)
        println("$obj -> isArray:${isArray(obj)}")

    return when (obj) {
        null -> "null"
        [...]
        isArray(obj) -> "Array"
        else -> "Other object"
    }
}

private fun isArray(obj: Any): Any = 
        obj is Array<*> ||
        [...]
        obj is IntArray
```

When I `assertEquals("Array", getType(intArrayOf(1,2,3,4)))` I get the following output:

```
[I@1e25b76 -> isArray:true

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Array
Actual   :Other object
```

So the `isArray` call is returning `true`, but it's not being recognised in the `when` clause. Why wouldn't it return `"Array"` here?

(I can work around this by putting this specific call before the `when` statement, but that's ugly)

Comment: Shouldn't `isArray()` return Boolean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues, first is that `isArray` needs to return `Boolean` and not `Any`.

The second problem is that you are using the form of [`when` expression](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) that has a fixed condition, `obj` and you are mixing that with the form of `when` that has no fixed condition and uses only boolean expressions.  The documentation isn't clear on the difference.

Fixed condition `when` expression:

```
when(obj) {
    null -> "null"
    is Array<*>, is IntArray, is DoubleArray -> "Array"
    else -> "Other object"
}
```

versus what you need to use, boolean expressions in a `when` expression:

```
when {                            // <--- no (obj) here
    obj == null -> "null"
    isArray(obj) -> "Array"
    else -> "Other object"
}
```

Although a much simpler way to find an array is this:

```
obj.javaClass.isArray
```

So you can change your `when` expression to simply be:

```
when {
    obj == null -> "null"
    obj.javaClass.isArray -> "Array"
    else -> "Other object"
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that - makes sense that I can't mix the two (although I wish I could :)). I'll merge the two into the one `when` clause.

Comment: I looked for the isArray, and I couldn't find it - that makes an even better answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
return when (obj) {
    null -> "null"
    [...]
    isArray(obj) -> "Array"
    else -> "Other object"
}
```

This seems to match the result of `isArray(obj)` (a `Boolean`) to the `obj` itself. Therefore, it's making the comparison `obj == true`, which is false.

If you want a `when` expression that uses boolean statements, you can do:

```
return when {
    obj == null -> "null"
    [...]
    isArray(obj) -> "Array"
    else -> "Other object"
}
```

Of course, this will require you to write a lot of `obj == x` checks.

Comment: That second option seems like a lot more work, thanks for the explanation here of what's going on!